# Convert a pandas column list of nested dictionaries into separate columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
Name    Level     Skills

Matt     10       [{'Invisibility': True, 
                    'Powerfist': False, 
                    {'Elemental':[{'Fire': 10,
                                  'Water': 20,
                                  'Wind': 15,
                                  'Earth': 10}],
                     'Race': 'Human'},
                    'Resources': [{'Mana' : True,
                                   'Energy':[{'Solar' : True,
                                              'Air' : True,
                                              'Hydro': True}]}]}]
Jack     12       [{'Invisibility': True, 
                    'Powerfist': False, 
                    {'Elemental':[{'Fire': 5,
                                  'Water': 13,
                                  'Wind': 10,
                                  'Earth': 16}]},
                     'Race': 'Giant'},
                    'Resources': [{'Mana' : True,
                                   'Energy':[{'Solar' : True,
                                              'Air' : False,
                                              'Hydro': True}]}]}]
Zack     20       [{'Invisibility': False, 
                    'Powerfist': True, 
                    {'Elemental':[{'Fire': 10,
                                  'Water': 10,
                                  'Wind': 10,
                                  'Earth': 10}]},
                     'Race': 'Elf'},
                    'Resources': [{'Mana' : True,
                                   'Energy':[{'Solar' : True,
                                              'Air' : True,
                                              'Hydro': True}]}]}]
```

As you can see, there is a list of dictionaries and list of nested dictionaries within the `Skills` column.

I want each and every **LAST** Key within each dictionary in the `Skills` column to have it's own column.

Like this:

```
 Name    Level    Invisibility     Powerfist    Fire   Water   Wind Earth   Race     Mana    Solar    Air    Hydro

 Matt     10      True             False        10     20      15     10    Human   True     True     True    True
 Jack     12      True             False         5     13      10     16    Giant   True     True     False    True
 Zack     20      False            True         10     10      10     10    Elf     True     True     True    True
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you create this dataframe from a JSON?

Comment: Yes, a 2 GB JSON file @AdityaK

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)